# edit Order Details Table in Thank You page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I edit Order Details Table in Thank You page in Woocommerce?

I tried the edit order-details template but it didnt work. Where does it get the information from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core template for *Thank You* page is located in `templates/checkout/thankyou.php` (basic order meta data).

The order details table is however loaded as a different template, located in `templates/order/order-details.php`. This template is loaded via pluggable function `woocommerce_order_details_table()`, so you can either **override this function** (not recommended), or **override the `order-details` template** (recommended).

**DO NOT** edit the WooCommerce core files (including templates) in the plugin's folders. Instead, override them in your theme/child-theme (learn [how to override](https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) WooCommerce templates from the docs).

However, if you only need to add or modify some parts of the code inside this template, **check if there are available** [**hooks**](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/) (*actions* and *filters*) inside, that would suit your use case. It is always better to use hooks if they are available, that way you can reduce the risk of template incompatibility in future WooCommerce releases.

Comment: I ended up using woocommerce_order_item_meta_end hook to add additional things to Order Details table. But thanks for the detailed answer, it definitely will be useful.